# Sellable Quantity Not Matching Product Quantity

Tags: stock, quantity

I have alot of SKU which the sellable quantity is less that the actual quantity. 
So quantity could be 5, but sellable quantity is 3.
I thought it could be open orders, or processing orders, so I deleted all of them using the mageplaza extension however the issue is not resolved

There are no open orders with the items in them, so is there a way to re-fresh the sellable quantity or delete whatever is causing it not to match the actual quantity

Any help greatly appreciated